# Proving the argument is either correct or incorrect

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The original argument is:

Our agreement states that either no crashes will occur in 2018’s first quarter (p)or the average response time of requests is under an hour(q). If the agreement is broken, you will pay 8000 dollars in damages(c). As shown in these records, the average response time is over two hours. You have paid us 8000 dollars. I can only conclude that a crash, or multiple crashes, have occurred."

Which I rewrote as:

pVq→¬c

c→¬pV¬q

However I'm unsure as to how to prove this argument as I can't see a logical method of rules to apply to this propositional statement.

Comment: Well for starters, realize that there is another option: the payment could have been made in error or as a sign of goodwill.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title that refers to the core issue in your question.  This will help attract solvers and help others in the future find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

They have promised $p \vee q$, so the promise is if this fails they will pay.  The first sentence should read $\lnot (p \vee q) \implies c$  For the second, you are given $q$ and $c$ and conclude $p$, so it would be written $(q \wedge c) \implies p$

The logic going from the first to the second is faulty.  Using just the symbols you could have $p$ false, $q$ true, and $c$ true.  That would make the first sentence true and the second false.  If you refer back to the sentences the symbols refer to it is hard to see how the response time can be two hours when there are no crashes to respond to, but that is not captured in the symbols you defined.